# Debian, cron, запуск php скрипта посекундно

Tags: php, debian, cron

Подскажите пожалуйста: мне необходимо некий php файл запускать раз в 10 секунд. Крон насколько я понял, меньше минуты не чирикает, люди пишут про фоновый процесс или бесконченый цикл, но я не пойму, как организовать его? Кто должен запускаться в фоне, каким образом и что он должно делать?

Спасибо

Comment: Какую задачу ты хочешь решить запуская скрипт каждую секунду?

Comment: хочу слушать редис ключ, в котором лежит массив, который пополняется данными.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для более частых запусков или для программ, который сами не умеют работать в режиме демона часто используют [Supervisor](http://supervisord.org/)

Демонизировать PHP процесс - не очень хорошая идея, сам язык не предполаегает таких сценариев использования. Но конечно, всё от ваших задач зависит и возможностей прострелить себе ноги полно :)

Comment: спасибо, Супервайзер действительно неплохое решение. но я к счастью нашел гораздо менее ресурсоемкий способ для своей задачи )